# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-31

Tags: android, flutter

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-31

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Tried installing tools in sdk manager, which failed

Comment: Do you have the android API 31 SDK installed on android studio?

Comment: Please include part of the error message in the title (the part that you would search for in a web search engine). It is an essential disambiguating component of your question. For more info on this guidance, see [ask], which instructs on how to write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title.

Comment: Yes , I have android API 31 SDK installed